# Collada file not importing

Tags: import, collada

I have a Collada file that isn't importing.

When i import it, Blender just closes, no log files or terminal windows stating an error, just closes.

I'm wondering if this is an error with Blender or rather the file, so i'll have it linked below. I'm using Blender 2.79b.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O2YewpqFFASzGmkeV-W5darLCaOE7ysy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The OpenCOLLADA validator reports some errors https://pastebin.com/d0KdruVm which mean the embedded texture fails to load.

Comment: Some of the coordinate data has [`nan`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) as a value that causes some error output but for me the file imports. Using 2.79 and 2.80 I get some parts that are out of position and some would appear to be missing, eg there are only two tyres/rims. By replacing `nan` with `0` the errors disappear but no extra parts show up.